# update_post_meta not saving to wordpress database

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am developing a plugin so that a real estate company can post their properties using custom post types. I can get the custom post types to show up on the admin menu. However, when i attempt to save a post the information in my custom meta box doesn't update to convey the changes. I am curious as to if it has to do with the save_post hook or if it is something else I am not seeing. The code below is my entire plugin.

```
<?php
/*
* Plugin Name: Real Estate Post Type
*/


register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'realEstatePostTypeActivation');

function realEstatePostTypeActivation(){
}

function my_admin(){    
    add_meta_box(
    'residential_meta_box',
    'Property Information',
    'displayPostMetaBox',
    'residentialProperty',
    'normal');

    add_meta_box(
    'commercial_meta_box',
    'Property Information',
    'displayPostMetaBox',
    'commercialProperty',
    'normal');  

}

add_action('admin_init', 'my_admin');

function displayPostMetaBox($post){

    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

    $address = !empty($meta['address']) ? $meta['address'] : '';
    $rent = !empty($meta['rent']) ? $meta['rent'] : '';
    $price = !empty($meta['price']) ? $meta['price'] : '';
    $bedrooms = !empty($meta['bedrooms']) ? $meta['bedrooms'] : '';
    $bathrooms = !empty($meta['bathrooms']) ? $meta['bathrooms'] : '';
    $sqft = !empty($meta['sqft']) ? $meta['sqft'] : '';
    $lot = !empty($meta['district']) ? $meta['lot'] : '';
    $smoker = !empty($meta['smoker']) ? $meta['smoker'] : '';
    $basement = !empty($meta['basement']) ? $meta['basement'] : '';
    $finished = !empty($meta['finished']) ? $meta['finished'] : '';
    $garage = !empty($meta['garage']) ? $meta['garage'] : '';
    $cars = !empty($meta['cars']) ? $meta['cars'] : '';
    $pet = !empty($meta['pet']) ? $meta['pet'] : '';
    $style = !empty($meta['style']) ? $meta['style'] : '';
    $notes = !empty($meta['notes']) ? $meta['notes'] : '';

?>

    <label for="address">Address</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="address" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $address; ?>"><br />

    <label for="rent">Rent</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="rent" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $rent; ?>"><br />

    <label for="price">House Price</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="price" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"><br />

    <label for="bedrooms">Bedrooms</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="bedrooms" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $bedrooms; ?>"><br />

    <label for="bathrooms">Bathrooms</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="bathrooms" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $bathrooms; ?>"><br />

    <label for="sqft">Square Feet</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="sqft" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $sqft; ?>"><br />

    <label for="lot">Lot size</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="lot" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $lot; ?>"><br />

    <label for="district">School District</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="district" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $district; ?>"><br />

    <input type="checkbox" size="80" name="basement" value="<?php echo $basement; ?>">
    <span>Has basement?</span><br />

    <input type="checkbox" size="80" name="finished" value="<?php echo $finished; ?>">
    <span>Finished basement?</span><br />

    <input type="checkbox" size="80" name="garage" value="<?php echo $garage; ?>">
    <span>Has garage?</span><br />

    <label for="cars">Number of cars?</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="cars" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $cars; ?>"><br />

    <input type="checkbox" size="80" name="smoker" value="<?php echo $smoker; ?>">
    <span>Allows smokers?</span><br />

    <input type="checkbox" size="80" name="pet" value="<?php echo $pet; ?>">
    <span>Allows pets?</span><br />

    <label for="style">Style of house</label>
    <select name="housestyle">
        <option<?php if($style == "none"){ echo 'selected="select"'; } ?> value="none">Select the style of house.</option>
        <option<?php if($style == "ranch"){ echo 'selected="select"'; } ?> value="ranch">Ranch Style</option>
        <option<?php if($style == "bi-level"){ echo 'selected="select"'; } ?> value="bi-level">Bi-level</option>
        <option<?php if($style == "tri-level"){ echo 'selected="select"'; } ?> value="tri-level">Tri-level</option>
    </select><br />

    <label for="notes">Additional Notes</label><br />
    <textarea name="notes" class="widefat" style="resize: none; height: 200px;"><?php echo $notes; ?></textarea>

    <?php
}

function addPropertyFields($post_id, $post, $update){

if($post->post_type == 'residentialProperty'){

    if(isset($_REQUEST['rent'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'rent', $_REQUEST['rent']);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['price'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'price', $_REQUEST['price']);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['address'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'address', $_REQUEST['address']);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['bedrooms'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'bedrooms', $_REQUEST['bedrooms']);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['bathrooms'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'bathrooms', $_REQUEST['bathrooms']);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['sqft'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'sqft', $_REQUEST['sqft']);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['district'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'district', $_REQUEST['district']);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['smoker'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'smoker', $_REQUEST['smoker']);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['pet'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'pet', $_REQUEST['pet']);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['housestyle'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'housestyle', $_REQUEST['housestyle']);
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['notes'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'notes', $_REQUEST['notes']);
    }
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'addPropertyFields', 99, 3);

function residentialPostType(){
    register_post_type('residentialProperty',
    array( 'labels' => array(
    'name' => __('Residential Properties'), 
    'singular_name' => __('Residential Property'),
    'add_new' => __('New Residential Property'),
    'add_new_item' => __('New Residential Property'),
    'edit' => __('Edit'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Property'),
    'new_item' => __('New Property'),
    'view' => __('View'),
    'view_item' => __('View Property'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Properties'),
    'not_found' => __('No Properties Found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Properties Found in Trash')),
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'title'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slugs' => 'residential')
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'residentialPostType');

function commercialPostType(){
    register_post_type('commercialProperty',
    array( 'labels' => array(
    'name' => __('Commercial Properties'), 
    'singular_name' => __('Commercial Property'),
    'add_new' => __('New Commercial Property'),
    'add_new_item' => __('New Commercial Property'),
    'edit' => __('Edit'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Property'),
    'new_item' => __('New Property'),
    'view' => __('View'),
    'view_item' => __('View Property'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Properties'),
    'not_found' => __('No Properties Found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Properties Found in Trash')),

    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'title'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slugs' => 'commercial')
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'commercialPostType');

?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This post's title was edited to ensure clarity with the issue i was having. I solved it on my own below. Hope this will be of value to others with this problem.

Comment: Kindly post only the code that is necessary to reproduce this issue. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I could not find what was holding back the functionality of my product. I could not replicate wether or not a certain function was not triggering or if there is something I was not educated on, that needs to be added to my current code. So what you are telling me is null and void. (pun intended)

Comment: When you're dealing with the `custom meta boxes`, what is the need to share your code showing how you register the custom post type? Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's a mistake around line 45 of your code. There's no index called `lot` defined.

Next, what you're trying to display in your custom field is an array of values retrieved from the database. Try adding an index to it.

Then, try removing the code where it checks for the type of post before executing the function hooked to the `save_post` action.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is within the function tied to the 'save_post' action. Instead of using the $post variable passed into addPropertyFields() I used the global $post variable.

```
function addPropertyFields($post_id){
    global $post;

    if($post->post_type != "property"){
        return;
    }

    add_post_meta($post_id, 'address', $_POST['address']) or update_post_meta($post_id, 'address', $_POST['address'], get_post_meta($post_id, 'address', true));
}

add_action('save_post', 'addPropertyFields');
```